# SQL AND/OR conditions for two tables

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

Supposed that we have classes Person, Character, and PersonCharacter and their corresponding structure in following data structure and data in MySQL database.

```
table persons
[
  { id: 1, name: peter },
  { id: 2, name: mary },
  { id: 3, name: joe },
  { id: 4, name: paul },
  { id: 5, name: may },
]

table characters
[
  { id: 101, description: cheerful },
  { id: 102, description: nervous },
  { id: 103, description: greedy },
  { id: 104, description: sincere },
  { id: 105, description: naive },
  { id: 106, description: firm },
]

table person_characters
[
  {id: 1000, person_id: 1, character_id: 101},
  {id: 1001, person_id: 1, character_id: 103},
  {id: 1002, person_id: 1, character_id: 106},
  {id: 1003, person_id: 2, character_id: 102},
  {id: 1004, person_id: 2, character_id: 104},
  {id: 1005, person_id: 3, character_id: 102},
  {id: 1006, person_id: 3, character_id: 105},
  {id: 1007, person_id: 4, character_id: 104},
  {id: 1008, person_id: 5, character_id: 101},
  {id: 1009, person_id: 5, character_id: 106},
]
```

How can I write a SQL statement, if possible with help of Rails, that can find out that with persons who have particular characters? For example, persons with character both firm and cheerful are may and peter.

The question seems typical but it is hard to find the answer by search engines.

Comment: Do you already know the "character" id or would you need to look that up? [This is essentially a JOIN query but would need to go a layer deeper to cross-reference the character id if you don't already have it.]

Comment: I would need to look that up.

Comment: `PersonCharacter` isn't a very meaningful data element name, IMO. How about `Personality`?

Comment: @onedaywhen: the above format is pretty standard to show that it's a relationship table.

Comment: @Brad Christie: "is pretty standard" -- sure, it's one school of thought but breaks down for relationships between entities of the same type e.g. what kind of relationship would PersonPerson be? ;) Also, it can be quite jarring (someone once likened them to compound nouns in German e.g. Plinkenplankenplunkenbox). Another school of thought is to use a logical collection name. Note this equally applies to entity tables as an alternative using the plural term e.g. `Personnel` rather than `Employees`.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Well, whatever the approach, I find only one thing matters: readability to the developer. ;-) Moving forward, you like descriptive high-level names, @OmniBus likes low-level noun and noun-associations. To each his/her own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  persons.*
FROM    persons
  JOIN  person_characters
  ON    person_characters.person_id ON persons.id
    AND
      -- vvv Method one, we already have the character IDs: vvv
      person_characters.character_id IN (101,106)
      -- ^^^ /Method one ^^^

      -- vvv Method two, we need to look them up vvv
      person_characters.character_id IN (
        SELECT characters.id
        FROM   characters
        WHERE  characters.description IN ('cheerful','firm')
      )
      -- ^^^ /Method two ^^^
```

**NOTE** use only one of those statements after the AND inside the join. I'm just showing either approach (if you do or do not have the ID(s) of the characters(s) to look for.

Answer (score 0):

> persons who have particular
>   characters?

One character trait per query or multiple (e.g. "persons who are both 'nervous' and 'firm'")?

If multiple, put the parameters ('nervous' and 'firm') in a table then use [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).